# Basic C# Dice Game

Tags: c#, dice

I am new to c# and coding in general. To try and improve my skills I am trying to create a basic game where two players roll a dice and keep record of their score. The player wins by reaching 20. Each player takes turns rolling a dice adding their first roll to their second and so on until one of them reaches 20. A player can roll the dice again if they roll a six.

The current code I have is:

---

```
        do
        {

            Console.Write("Enter the name of Player 1: ");
            Player[0] = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter the name of Player 2: ");
            Player[1] = Console.ReadLine();

            Random DiceRandom = new Random();
            DiceThrow[0] = DiceRandom.Next(1, 7);

            int i = 0;
            while (i <= 1)
            {
                DiceThrow[0 + i] = DiceRandom.Next(1, 7);
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write(Player[0 + i] + " rolled a " + DiceThrow[0 + i]);
                if (DiceThrow[0 + i] != 6) i++;
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
            PlayerTotal[0] = DiceThrow[0];
            PlayerTotal[1] = DiceThrow[1];


            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write(Player[0] + " currently has " + PlayerTotal[0]);
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write(Player[1] + " currently has " + PlayerTotal[1]);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        while (PlayerTotal[0] == 20);
        while (PlayerTotal[1] == 20);
```

---

What I am specifically struggling with is adding the players first roll to there second roll. And if a player rolls a six that it adds the 6 to what they get in the re-roll.

Any help at all will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of concerns with your code here:

1. you are asking the player name inside the loop
2. You are initializing the Random generator inside the loop (this can cause same results on different loops because the random generator can use the same seed)
3. You are resetting totals using = instead of +=
4. The stop condition is totals == 20 instead of total < 20
5. you are using two while statement instead of an AND (&&) condition

This is just a brief overview..

This can be a solution:

```
  Console.Write("Enter the name of Player 1: ");
  Player[0] = Console.ReadLine();
  Console.Write("Enter the name of Player 2: ");
  Player[1] = Console.ReadLine();

  Random DiceRandom = new Random();

  do
    {

        int i = 0;
        while (i <= 1)
        {
            int thisThrow = DiceRandom.Next(1, 6);
            DiceThrow[0 + i] += thisThrow;
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write(Player[0 + i] + " rolled a " + thisThrow);
            if (thisThrow != 6) i++;
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
        PlayerTotal[0] += DiceThrow[0];
        PlayerTotal[1] += DiceThrow[1];


        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write(Player[0] + " currently has " + PlayerTotal[0]);
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write(Player[1] + " currently has " + PlayerTotal[1]);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
    while (PlayerTotal[0] < 20 && PlayerTotal[1] < 20);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply and the concerns, coding is completely new to me so I was not aware of those concerns.

The solution you have provided is almost perfect. Except if a player rolls a 6 and then rolls a 2 it saves the number 2 as their PlayerTotal instead of an 8.

Comment: yes I've corrected the code: DiceThrow[0 + i] should be incremented (with +=) instead of overwritten (with =)

Comment: It does add the numbers together, but players are able to roll numbers greater than 6, which should not be allowed. Any idea how I could fix this?

Comment: this is because you are using Next(1, 7), this will return number from 1 to 7, I think you should use Next(1, 6) in order to stop at 6. Next(minValue, MaxValue) includes bounds

Comment: No I was getting results such as:

Player1 rolled a 12

and 

Player 2 rolled a 8

Comment: Ah I've understand, I've edited my code above, it is simpler for you to use a local variable in order to save the current result and operate with it. This result is then added to the total.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're reseting the previous scores with these lines:

```
PlayerTotal[0] = DiceThrow[0];
PlayerTotal[1] = DiceThrow[1];
```

You should change it to use `+=` like this:

```
PlayerTotal[0] += DiceThrow[0];
PlayerTotal[1] += DiceThrow[1];
```

Which is like saying: `PlayerTotal[0] = PlayerTotal[0] + DiceThrow[0];`

Other then that, there are a few more problems in your code.

For instance, you have one `Do` at the beginning of the code but 2 `while`s...
You probably want to create one `While` with an *AND* statement. Also, the `Do` statement needs to be *after* you get the user's names...

For instance:
     // Get User names

```
 do
 {
    // All your Dice throwing logic
 }
 while (PlayerTotal[0] != 20 && PlayerTotal[1] != 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int i = 0;
    while (i <= 1)
    {
        int thisThrow = DiceRandom.Next(1, 6);
        DiceThrow[0 + i] += thisThrow;
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write(Player[0 + i] + " rolled a " + thisThrow);
        if (thisThrow != 6) i++;
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
    PlayerTotal[0] += DiceThrow[0];
    PlayerTotal[1] += DiceThrow[1];


    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write(Player[0] + " currently has " + PlayerTotal[0]);
    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write(Player[1] + " currently has " + PlayerTotal[1]);
    Console.ReadLine();
```